# Web Service call in Sandox Visual Webpart

Tags: sandbox-solution, visual-web-part

I have web service which I want to call in my sandbox visual web part.

when I'm call web service method in web part at that time I'm getting this error
`Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.`

Answer (score 1):

We can not call webservice in sand box solution(It's does not support).The reason behind of this sand box solution support only full trust code.One or more assemblies referenced by the XmlSerializer cannot be called  from partially trusted code.

You need to extend the sandboxed solution by making use of SPProxyOperation and SPProxyOperationArgs.
Some examples of extending a sandboxed solutions are

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-12-SharePoint_2010_Sandboxed_Solutions__Full_Trust__Proxies.aspx

http://vimleshtiwari.blogspot.com/2010/06/calling-web-service-in-sandbox-solution.html

Also check : http://sandboxwebservice.codeplex.com/